# Objetos referenciados y apuntadores de una clase

Tags: c++, clase, punteros

Tengo un programa que tiene que crear un arbol a partir de un grafo, para eso tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
NodoArbol<Vertice>* GrafoMatriz::getBP(bool AR, string origen){
   int num_pf=1;
   int indiceV = this->getIndicePorNombre(origen);
   Nodo<Vertice>* nodo = new Nodo<Vertice>(this->vertices[indiceV]);
   NodoArbol<Vertice>* raiz = new NodoArbol<Vertice>(nodo , num_pf);
   Arbol<Vertice>* BP = new Arbol<Vertice>(raiz, AR);
   Lista<bool>* Visitados = new Lista<bool>();
   for(int i=0; i<this->getMaximoVertices();i++){
      Visitados->add(false,Visitados);
   }
   Visitados->marcar(Visitados, indiceV);
   raiz->addHijo(aplicarBP(AR,Visitados,origen,++num_pf));
   return BP->getRaiz();
}

//Funcion que obtiene el Bosque en profundidad del grafo
NodoArbol<Vertice>* GrafoMatriz::aplicarBP(bool conAristasRetroceso, 
  Lista<bool>* Visitados, string origen, int num){
  NodoArbol<Vertice>* nodo = nullptr;
  Cola<Vertice>* adyacentes = this->getAdyacentesDeV(origen);
  while(!adyacentes->vacia(adyacentes)){
    int indiceW = this->getIndicePorNombre(adyacentes->getPrimero()->getDato().getNombre());
    if(!(Visitados->getValor(Visitados,indiceW))){
            origen = this->vertices[indiceW].getNombre();
            Nodo<Vertice>* nodoHijo = new Nodo<Vertice>(this->vertices[indiceW]);
            nodo = new NodoArbol<Vertice>(nodoHijo,num);
            Visitados->marcar(Visitados, indiceW);
            nodo->addHijo(aplicarBP(conAristasRetroceso,Visitados,origen,++num));
        }else{
            adyacentes->quitaDeCola(adyacentes);
        }
}

return nodo;
}
```

En la parte de agregar un hijo tengo una lista para agregar los hijos de este 
en la clase `NodoArbol`:

```
Lista<NodoArbol<T>>* hijos;
```

El metodo es el siguiente:

```
   template <class T>
   void NodoArbol<T>::addHijo( NodoArbol<T>* hijo){
   this->hijos->add(hijo,this->hijos);
   this->num_hijos++;
   }
```

Y el codigo de add en Lista esta asi:

```
Nodo<T>* nodoNuevo = new Nodo<T>(x,nullptr);
Nodo<T>* estePrimero = lista->primero;
if (estePrimero==nullptr){
    estePrimero = nodoNuevo;
    estePrimero->ponerEnlace(nullptr);
    lista->primero = estePrimero;
}else{
    Nodo<T>* temporal = estePrimero;
    while(!(temporal->getEnlace()==nullptr)){
        temporal= temporal->getEnlace();
    }
    temporal->ponerEnlace(nodoNuevo);
}
```

Y el constructor de la clase nodo

```
  Nodo(T x, Nodo<T>*sig)
       {
         dato = x;
         enlace = sig;
       }
```

Ahora viene el problema, cuando intento agregar un `nodoArbol` a esta lista me tira el siguiente error:

```
..\src\Nodo.h:39:9: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'NodoArbol<Vertice>*' to 'NodoArbol<Vertice>'
```

El error lo tira en esta linea:

```
    Nodo<T>* nodoNuevo = new Nodo<T>(x,nullptr);
```

Creo que tengo un problema con respecto a las referencias de las clases, pero en este sentido no se que hacer.

Comment: Consejos: 1. Si pones un error, pon el mensaje **completo**. En tu pregunta falta la línea y el punto que genera el error. 2. Pon, al menos, la firma de **todas** las funciones **involucradas** en el error. Nosotros no tenemos más código que el que nos muestras... y si nos falta información dificilmente podremos darte una respuesta satisfactoria. En este caso falta, al menos, la firma de `addHijo`... si es que es ahí donde se genera el error

Comment: Si disculpa ahora añadi los metodos que me dan problema y la linea donde me tira error

Comment: Lo siento pero sigue faltando información. El error está hablando de `NodoArbol<T>`, no dice nada de `Nodo<T>`... por otro lado estos mensajes de error suelen indicar **el código** que genera el error y, en la línea siguiente, unos símbolos que precisan qué elemento está generando el problema ¿Eres capaz de preparar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema? Si es así publica ese código al completo...